# Clear text from document body

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that is checking if the text entered is a number or not. When the user clicks on the enter button, and the text is not a number it displays a message on the screen. If I keep pressing the enter the text keeps appearing but I want to clear the text each time the enter button is pressed so it doesn't keep repeating.

[image]

HMTL:

```
<div>
 Enter Distance: <input id="distance" type="text" name="txtDistance"><br>
 <p>
        <button id="enter" role="button">Enter</button>
      </p>
 </div>

 <div id="docBod">
    </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById('enter').addEventListener('click', function(event){

if(isNaN(document.getElementById('distance').value)){
    var docBod = document.body;
    var Error = document.createElement('h4');
    Error.textContent = "Please enter a number";
    docBod.appendChild(Error);
 }else{

 }

});
```

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you could just make the text field  a number only input so they can not put in any text. <input id="distance" type="number" name="txtDistance">

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` to add the element to the body

```js
document.getElementById('enter').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  if (isNaN(document.getElementById('distance').value)) {
    var docBod = document.body;
    docBod.innerHTML += '<h4>Please enter a number</h4>'
  } else {

  }

});
```

```html
<div>
  Enter Distance: <input id="distance" type="text" name="txtDistance"><br>
  <p>
    <button id="enter" role="button">Enter</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="docBod">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have read your question correctly, but the above answer doesn't clear the field like you've mentioned. I've created the below jsfiddle, let me know if this answers your question.

https://jsfiddle.net/pon962ke/3/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox">
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
<p id="error" style="display: none;">Please enter a number</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<div>
 Enter Distance: <input id="distance" type="text" name="txtDistance"><br>
 <p>
    <button id="enter" role="button">Enter</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="docBod">
 <h4 id="num-error"></h4>
</div>
```

And then in the JavaScript:

```
var numError = document.querySelector('#num-error');
document.getElementById('enter').addEventListener('click', function(event){

if(isNaN(document.getElementById('distance').value)){
   numError.textContent = "Please enter a number";
}else{
   numError.textContent = "";
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem you're running into is the line:

```
var Error = document.createElement('h4');
```

This creates a new `<h4>` element every time the user attempts to submit a non-numeric character, and ultimately your function appends that to the page.

One option to avoid that problem is to find the existing `<h4>` element on the page, if it exists, and use that element; otherwise create a new one:

```
// here we use document.querySelector() to find the first, if any,
// element that matches the selector; if no such element is found
// document.querySelector() returns null, and we move on to creating
// a new <h4> element:
var Error = document.querySelector('h4') || document.createElement('h4');
```

This does, of course, mean that the same message is being added to the same element, which does nothing to draw the user's attention.

So, to draw the user's attention there are two obvious solutions:

1. empty/remove the element when the `<input>` is focused, and add it back if a new error is made, or
2. leave the error in place, but add a flash of colour with, for example, a CSS transition.

To that end, then:

```
// because we use the elements more than once, we cache them:
const button = document.getElementById('enter'),
  input = document.getElementById('distance');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // other than the use of the 'input' variable, this function
  // is unchanged from your original:
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {

    // using the docBod element, retrieving by its id,
    // instead of the document.body:
    var docBod = document.getElementById('docBod'),
      Error = document.createElement('h4');

    Error.textContent = "Please enter a number";
    docBod.appendChild(Error);
  }
});

// here we bind the anonymous function as the event-handler
// for the focus event:
input.addEventListener('focus', function() {

  // we find the existing <h4> element in the document, if
  // one exists, and cache it:
  const temp = document.querySelector('h4');

  // if no element was found then temp will be null:
  if (temp) {
    // if temp was found, then we use ChildNode.remove()
    // to remove it from the document:
    temp.remove();
  }
  // for user convenience we could also select the <input>
  // value:
  // input.select();
});
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById('enter'),
  input = document.getElementById('distance');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {
    var docBod = document.getElementById('docBod'),
      Error = document.createElement('h4');

    Error.textContent = "Please enter a number";
    docBod.appendChild(Error);
  }
});

input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  const temp = document.querySelector('h4');
  if (temp) {
    temp.remove();
  }
  //input.select()
});
```

```html
<div>
  Enter Distance: <input id="distance" type="text" name="txtDistance"><br>
  <p>
    <button id="enter" role="button">Enter</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="docBod">
</div>
```

To add a flash of colour to grab attention:

```
// again, caching the relevant elements:
const button = document.getElementById('enter'),
  input = document.getElementById('distance');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {

    // as above, I've chosen to use the element with the id of
    // docBod to assign to the variable of the same name:
    var docBod = document.getElementById('docBod'),

      // as in the first answer we here look for the existing
      // element, if it doesn't exist we create it:
      Error = document.querySelector('h4') || document.createElement('h4');

    Error.textContent = "Please enter a number";
    docBod.appendChild(Error);
  }
});
```

The above JavaScript relies on CSS to provide the animation:

```
// we create a CSS animation to animate the colour of the
// element to which the animation is bound from transparent
// (adjust to an appropriate colour of your choice) to
// #f90 (at the 75% point in the animation) and then back
// to transparent:
@keyframes attentionGrab {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #f90;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

h4 {
  /*
    'attentionGrab': the animation-name, the name of the
                     animation that we're using,
    '1.5s': the animation-duration, in seconds ('s'),
    'ease-in-out': the animation-timing-function,
    '1': the animation-iteration-count, here we play the
         animation once.
  */
  animation: attentionGrab 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
}
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById('enter'),
  input = document.getElementById('distance');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (isNaN(input.value)) {
    var docBod = document.getElementById('docBod'),
      Error = document.querySelector('h4') || document.createElement('h4');

    Error.textContent = "Please enter a number";
    docBod.appendChild(Error);
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes attentionGrab {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #f90;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

h4 {
  animation: attentionGrab 1.5s ease-in-out 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Enter Distance: <input id="distance" type="text" name="txtDistance"><br>
  <p>
    <button id="enter" role="button">Enter</button>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="docBod">
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).
  - [`animation-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration).
  - [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count)
  - [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function).
- JavaScript:

  - [`childNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Bibliography:

- "[Using CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)," at Mozilla Developer Network.